# Why this appears to my procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is what I do:

```
use FCT;  
declare @CORREO varchar(80)  
declare @SALT varchar(100)  
declare @PASS varchar(100)  
declare @PASSWORDECRYPT VARCHAR(100)  
declare @Nuevo INT  
set @CORREO = '123456@gmail.com'  
set @PASS = 'xyz123%'  
set @Nuevo = 1  
exec PROC_RegistroUsuario @CORREO, @SALT, @PASS, @PASSWORDECRYPT, @Nuevo
```

After executing this appears:

> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure PROC_RegistroUsuario, Line 58
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Password', table 'Facturas.dbo.aspnet_Membership'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

And this is my Stored Procedure:

```
USE [FCT]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_RegistroUsuario] @CORREO VARCHAR(80), @SALT VARCHAR(100), @PASS VARCHAR(100), @PASSWORDECRYPT VARCHAR(100), @Nuevo INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @USERID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @MensajeRegreso VARCHAR(8000),
        @CantidadContactosEmpresa INT,
        @EmpresaRFC char(13)

SET @USERID = (SELECT [UserId] FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE [UserName] = @CORREO)

IF @Nuevo IN (1, 2)
BEGIN
    SET @CantidadContactosEmpresa = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[EmpresaUser] WHERE [EmpresaUser_Empresa] IN (SELECT [EmpresaUser_Empresa] FROM [dbo].[EmpresaUser] WHERE [EmpresaUser_Email] = @CORREO))
    IF @USERID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_Users
                    ( ApplicationId ,
                      UserId ,
                      UserName ,
                      LoweredUserName ,
                      MobileAlias ,
                      IsAnonymous ,
                      LastActivityDate
                    )
            SELECT TOP 1 ApplicationId , -- ApplicationId - uniqueidentifier
                      NEWID() , -- UserId - uniqueidentifier
                      @CORREO , -- UserName - nvarchar(256)
                      LOWER(@CORREO) , -- LoweredUserName - nvarchar(256)
                      NULL , -- MobileAlias - nvarchar(16)
                      0 , -- IsAnonymous - bit
                      GETDATE()  -- LastActivityDate - datetime
                    FROM dbo.aspnet_Applications

            SET @USERID = (SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = @CORREO)

            INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_Membership
                    ( ApplicationId ,
                      UserId ,
                      Password ,
                      PasswordFormat ,
                      PasswordSalt ,
                      MobilePIN ,
                      Email ,
                      LoweredEmail ,
                      PasswordQuestion ,
                      PasswordAnswer ,
                      IsApproved ,
                      IsLockedOut ,
                      CreateDate ,
                      LastLoginDate ,
                      LastPasswordChangedDate ,
                      LastLockoutDate ,
                      FailedPasswordAttemptCount ,
                      FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart ,
                      FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount ,
                      FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart ,
                      Comment
                    )
            SELECT ApplicationId , -- ApplicationId - uniqueidentifier
                      @USERID , -- UserId - uniqueidentifier
                      @PASSWORDECRYPT , -- Password - nvarchar(128)
                      1 , -- PasswordFormat - int
                      @SALT , -- PasswordSalt - nvarchar(128)
                      NULL , -- MobilePIN - nvarchar(16)
                      @CORREO , -- Email - nvarchar(256)
                      LOWER(@CORREO) , -- LoweredEmail - nvarchar(256)
                      'Pregunta' , -- PasswordQuestion - nvarchar(256)
                      @PASSWORDECRYPT , -- PasswordAnswer - nvarchar(128)
                      1 , -- IsApproved - bit
                      0 , -- IsLockedOut - bit
                      GETDATE() , -- CreateDate - datetime
                      GETDATE() , -- LastLoginDate - datetime
                      GETDATE() , -- LastPasswordChangedDate - datetime
                      '18990101' , -- LastLockoutDate - datetime
                      0 , -- FailedPasswordAttemptCount - int
                      '18990101' , -- FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart - datetime
                      0 , -- FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount - int
                      '18990101', -- FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart - datetime
                      @PASS  -- Comment - ntext
                    FROM dbo.[aspnet_Applications]

        /*Empresas*/

        INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles
                    ( UserId, RoleId )
            SELECT @USERID, -- UserId - uniqueidentifier
                      RoleId -- RoleId - uniqueidentifier
                  FROM dbo.aspnet_Roles WHERE RoleName IN ('Empresas')
    END

    ELSE

    BEGIN

        SET @PASS = (SELECT TOP 1 [EmpresaUser_Password] FROM [dbo].[EmpresaUser] WHERE [EmpresaUser_Email] = @CORREO ORDER BY [EmpresaUser_Email])

        UPDATE [dbo].[EmpresaUser] SET [EmpresaUser_Password] = @PASS WHERE [EmpresaUser_Email] = @CORREO

        SET @MensajeRegreso = 'El usuario ya existe dentro de la base de datos, se agregó la cuenta a esta empresa, el podrá ingresar con su antigua contraseña.'
    END
END

ELSE

BEGIN
    DECLARE @EnPerfil BIT

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] WHERE [UserId] = @USERID AND [RoleId] = (SELECT [UserId] FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Roles] WHERE [RoleName] = 'Empresas')) = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EnPerfil = 0
    END

    ELSE

    BEGIN
        SET @EnPerfil = 1
        SET @MensajeRegreso = 'El usuario ya cuenta con un perfil, no se puede cambiar la contraseña.'
    END

    IF @EnPerfil = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] SET [Password] = @PASSWORDECRYPT WHERE [UserId] = @USERID
        SET @MensajeRegreso = 'Datos contacto actualizados.'
    END
END

IF @Nuevo IN (0, 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT @MensajeRegreso AS Mensaje
END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't set `@PASSWORDECRYPT` before executing the stored procedure, so its value is still `NULL`.